# I want to print the largest value row which has 4 5 columns in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I want to print the largest value row which has 4 5 columns in c++. I have two classes one is cpu and other one is process. How can I send a value to cpu from process and after updating that value into array, cpu sends back to process.

Please give me a simple example.

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: Please tell me how can i print the row which has highest value

Comment: Please clarify what is meant by 4 5 columns(is this 4 or 5 columns?), what you are passing back to process from cpu, and how this is relevant to retrieving the largest value.

Comment: Actually i enter some processes details so the higher priority process will go to the cpu first.so for this i need to print first the complete row which has higher priority!!I have two classses one is cpu another one is process.All these information im taking into the some attributes of class process.so now i want to send the time of higher priority process to cpu then cpu reduce that value by updating into array of process class which has been initialed in process class.so cpu sends back that value after updating into an array of process class.

Comment: To send values to a class, such as one named `cpu`, you can either call a method in `cpu` class or modify a public data member in `cpu` class.

Answer (score 0):

### Finding Row with Maximum Value

The solution is very similar to finding the maximum number in a set of values.

You want maintain two variables, one that contains the running maximum value and another that maintains the row index that contains the maximum value.

After processing all the rows, print the row indicated by the row index.

Example:

```
unsigned int row_of_max = 0;
int max_value = -123456789;
for (unsigned int row = 0; row < MAXIMUM_ROWS; ++row)
{
  for (unsigned int col = 0; col < MAXIMUM_COLUMNS; ++col)
  {
    if (maxtrix[row][col] > max_value)
    {
      row_of_max = row;
      max_value = maxtrix[row][col];
    }
  }
}
```

The number of rows or columns, be it 4 5, is not significant; the algorithm is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

### Passing Values between two classes.

In general, one class has a receive method and another class calls the receive method with a value.

```
class CPU
{
  const unsigned int MAX_ROWS = 10U;
  const unsigned int MAX_COLS = 45U;
  int matrix[MAX_ROWS][MAX_VALUES];

public:  
  void receive(unsigned int row, unsigned int column, int value)
  {
    matrix[row][col] = value;
  }
};

class Process
{
  CPU & m_cpu_object;
public:
  Process(CPU & cpu_object)
  : m_cpu_object(cpu_object)
  { ; }

  void send_to_cpu(void)
  {
    for (unsigned int row = 0; row < 5; ++row)
    {
      for (unsigned int column = 0; column < 10; ++col)
      {
        m_cpu_object.receive(row, column, row * column);
      }
    }
  }
};

int main(void)
{
  CPU my_cpu;
  Process process_1(my_cpu);
  process.send_to_cpu();
  return 0;
}
```